# Monitor source code in C that synchronizes threads

Tags: c, synchronization, posix, mutex, barrier

I want to make a monitor that synchronizes n threads in C according to the following way: Each thread calls barrier_synch() method. First n-1 threads that call this method sleep. When the n-th thread calls this method, all sleeping threads wake up and then all threads continue the execution, while the barrier returns to the initial condition. This is a solution I found:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct barrier{
    int n, count;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
    int blocked;
}barrier;

void barrier_init(barrier *bar, int n){
    bar->n = n;
    bar->count = 0;
    pthread_mutex_init(&bar->mutex, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&bar->cond, NULL);
    bar->blocked = 1;
}

void barrier_synch(barrier *bar){
    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&bar->mutex);
        if (bar->blocked == 1) break;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&bar->mutex);
    }
    bar->count++;
    if(bar->count == bar->n){
        bar->blocked = 0;
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&bar->cond);
    }

    while(bar->blocked == 1){
        pthread_cond_wait(&bar->cond, &bar->mutex);
    }
    bar->count--;
    if(bar->count == 0){
        bar->blocked = 1;
    }
pthread_mutex_unlock(&bar->mutex);
}
```

Is this code correct? Can somebody explain me in simple words how this mechanism works?

Comment: This is far too broad as a question for such as site as SO.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt, this doesn't seem broad.  "How do I write my own OS over the weekend?" is broad.  This seems quite specific, albeit non-trivial.

Comment: This is too broad because he's asking if his code is correct. @Konstantinos Konstantini, please provide a more specific question by trying your code and asking about a specific problem.

Comment: He's also asking *how* it works.  When someone dumps 600 lines and asks if it works or if it is good they get sent to Code Review or whatnot.  This is basically one function.  We answer these kinds of questions all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [The Little Book of Semaphores](http://greenteapress.com/semaphores/) for all sorts of synchronization primitives and uses. It isn't in C, but it should help you in thinking about your code in a structured, correct way.